Big query API schedule job authorisation
I have
locals {
  creation_roles = {
    "cloud_scheduler_create" = "roles/cloudscheduler.admin"
  }

  running_roles = {
    "bigquery_job_user"    = "roles/bigquery.jobUser"
    "bigquery_data_editor" = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
    "bigquery_user"        = "roles/bigquery.user"
  }
}


resource "google_project_iam_member" "this" {
  for_each = local.creation_roles
  role     = each.value
  member   = "serviceAccount:${var.cloudscheduler_admin}"
  project  = var.project_id
}


resource "google_project_iam_member" "that" {
  for_each = local.running_roles
  role     = each.value
  member   = "serviceAccount:${var.service_account_email}"
  project  = var.project_id
}


resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "this" {
  name        = var.schedule_name
  description = "Run BigQuery DDL query daily"
  schedule    = var.caching_schedule
  project     = var.project_id
  region      = var.region

  http_target {
    http_method = "POST"
    uri         = "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/${var.project_id}/queries"

    body = base64encode(
      jsonencode({
        query = templatefile(
          var.sql_file_path,
          var.sql_template_vars
        ),
        useLegacySql = false
      })
    )

    headers = {
      "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    }

    oauth_token {
      service_account_email = var.service_account_email
      scope                 = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    }
  }

  depends_on = [
    google_project_iam_member.this,
    google_project_iam_member.that
  ]
}


where the query is reading from a google sheet. ie say:
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE  `${project_id}.${dataset_id}.${table_id}`
OPTIONS (
  format = 'GOOGLE_SHEETS',
  uris = ['${sheet_url}']
);


The schedule is created but the api call gives me an error "INVALID_ARGUMENT" (and not an unauthorised!) one. unfortunately I couldn't get the underlying big query logs to see what's going on.
I have checked that if I hardcode the auth header it succeeds. ie, use
gcloud auth print-access-token \
  --impersonate-service-account=${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL} \
  --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly | \
  sed 's/^/Bearer /'

and manually edit the schedule entry to not have the built in oauth token and have a Authorization header.
Also, I can do the same query using curl successfully. ie:
PROJECT_ID=""
DATASET_ID=""
TABLE_ID=""
SHEET_URL=""
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL=""
SCHEDULE_NAME=""

BQ_PAYLOAD=$(gcloud scheduler jobs describe ${SCHEDULE_NAME} \
  --location europe-west2 \
  --format=json | jq -r '.httpTarget.body' | base64 --decode)

curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token --impersonate-service-account=${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL} --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "$BQ_PAYLOAD" \
"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/queries" | jq

works just fine! so clearly the problem isn't the SQL bit. and it's not the service account bit either since the local curl works?
worth noting that if I add the "roles/drive.readonly" role, it doesn't let me add roles/drive.readonly to the service account, saying:

Error setting IAM policy for project "": googleapi: Error 400: Role roles/drive.readonly is not supported for this resource., badRequest

so I am out of ideas.
p.s. I have now realised I might be able to do this directly using a table creation instruction but the question still stands.

You can't rescope your gcloud auth token. You have to login again, with the correct scope at login time.

just to clarify: Is your issue with my script, that happens to work? perhaps you mean the reason it worked is I had previosuly done a login with the relevant login?
